# Mapping Id property in mongoDb to c#

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a nested document stored in MongoDB, such as:

```
{ 
  _id: 56f19c2663e43f940a7fab69, 
  propA: "some value",
  nestedItem: {
                propB: "nested property",
                leafItem: {
                            id: 1458607372380,
                            leafProp: "a leaf property"
                          }
               }
}
```

I am trying to map it to a set of C# classes:

```
public class FirstLevel {
     public ObjectId _id {get; set;}
     public string propA {get; set;}
     public SecondLevel nestedItem {get; set;}
}

public class SecondLevel {
     public string propB {get; set;}
     public ThirdLevel leafItem {get; set;}
}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class ThirdLevel {
     public long id {get; set;}
     public string leafProp {get; set;}
}
```

If I remove the 'BsonIgnoreExtraElements', it gives an error that `An error occurred while deserializing the leafItem property of class ConsoleApplication1.SecondLevel: Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class ConsoleApplication1.ThirdLevel.`

If I keep the ignore elements, it populates 0 in the id.

If I have a member for [BsonExtraElements], it does show id as a property and also shows the value.

To give a background on the id value, I am creating this JSON structure in a client browser application, and using new Date().valueOf() to get a unique number for id.

When I view the documents in MongoVue, I see that the type is recognized as Double, and the bson extra elements member also shows it as a double type.

I am simply trying to get the value into the class member. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using long if it double ???

Comment: Forgot to mention, I tried all different things, long, double, string... it never populates.

Comment: I think the problem is the property name. Could you try adding `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int64)]` to the `id` property or rename the `id` property to something else.

Comment: Thanks... will try and let you know. I am pretty sure changing name of property from id will fix this but that is not what i would like to do (as it would mean changing a lot of code).

Comment: Ok I tried but the id is always 0. I had to eventually add a new field.